# UIwebView links delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with some links in it. When I click the link, there's a delay of about 2-3 seconds before the link is loaded. Is this how it's suppose to be or is there a setting I can change?
Thanks.

Comment: The delay is annoying, but it's sort of funny that a delay of maybe half a second becomes "2-3 seconds" in people's minds.

Answer (score 11):

In iOS5 the `UIScrollView` belonging to a `UIWebView` has been exposed so that you can change its behavior. So to remove the click delays you can simply do:

```
[webView.scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO]
```

This way you don't have to use any javascript libraries to remove the delay.

As a bonus, you can make the scrolling in a `UIWebView` feel a bit more native by changing the decelerationRate:

```
[webView.scrollView setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal]
```

Comment: Unfortunately setDelaysContentTouches is the touchdown delay, whereas the click delay is caused by waiting for doubletap. This solution doesn't appear to fix that.

Comment: That fixed my exact problem. And +1 for the more native scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that after clicking the link there is a delay *before* the the link is highlighted, this has to do with how the touches are handled by the UIWebView. I doubt that this can account for the whole 2-3 secs delay, but anyway refer to [this post](http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone) to remove it.

If you mean that after clicking on a link it takes 2-3 seconds until you can see the page rendered, then it is (unfortunately) normal. `UIWebView` is known for being slow at rendering even a simple page.

Comment: You can also work around the UIWebView touch delay by using [FastClick](http://assanka.net/content/tech/2011/08/26/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are calling the load method on main thread or not. If you are testing it on Simulator then calling a method on secondary thread takes some time to execute rather than crashing or throwing an exception. Replace such call (if any) by `performSelectorOnMainThread` method.