# Fast button vs removing touch delay on ios UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a webapp for ios. I wanted to implement the so-called 'fast click button' detailed such as:

http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone
https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

but I see from other posts that in ios5 we can get access to the UIScrollView belonging to a UIWebView so that we can remove the click delays. We can do this via:

[UIwebView links delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471188/uiwebview-links-delay)

```
[webView.scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:NO]
```

Is this the recommended approach now? This seems a lot simpler since I am only targeting ios.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, setDelaysContentTouches doesn't eliminate the 300ms delay. At least, it didn't in my testing.  However, the javascript solution to linked to did work for me.